# I converted my HTML template to Wordpress but got problems

Tags: html, wordpress

I converted my html theme to wordpress but its not working. Everything on the main page is showing a long list. I need immediate help to solve my problem. Any expert here to help me please

Comment: You need to show what code you've tried/written/what errors are showing. Otherwise we have no way of helping

Comment: here is my website url. ABC123.agency. I didn't do anything. Just extract the zip file in my theme and make style.css and index.php file to come on main. check my url and you'll come to know what I'm talking about

Answer (score 0):

[image: No CSS,JS]
None of your css, js files are loading. they are not found in the directory you specified

Answer (score 0):

Okay, thank you for linking your site.  To piggyback off @vagelis answer, none of your JS or CSS files are loading.  The reason for this is because its looking for your files in  a place they are not.  All your css/js files are in your theme folder, which isn't where they are current linked.

There is any easy fix for this though.

```
<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>
```

which automatically echos the url of your theme folder.

So for instance,

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/reset.css">
```

Should be  `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/style/reset.css">`

Comment: thanks for your reply. You got my problem in fact you're the first person of hundreds of forums who got the right problem for me. Where Would I supposed to put these links in my directory. Thanks again

Comment: Thanks man. Just tell me where to put these codes in my directory. You're the first person who got the right problem.

Comment: On whatever .php file all your html is on.  Unless you've split in up so that your header and footer's are correctly in a header.php and footer.php file. 
 Then change it there.  Changes all your css and js links to add that bit of PHP code.

Comment: Someone told me that my functions.php file is not working correctly, what do you say about that.

Comment: Well, I did that. I did split all header, footer, menu and other things. So Am I suppose to ad this code in index.php or style.css?

Comment: you might have to put in in your index.php if you've put a link to either your JS or your CSS there.  Again, anywhere you've put a link or script tag, you need to put that code.  If there's a way to do that via functions.php, I don't personally know of it, hence not suggesting it.

Comment: also if I've provided a solution please check mark the answer so it becomes the accepted answer.  Thank you

Comment: no buddy, your method don't work for me (may be just because of wrong replacement). Here is what my index.php file look like

Comment: <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
require_once('header.php');
if(file_exists(basename(($_GET['page']!='' ? $_GET['page'] : 'home') . '.php')))
 require_once(basename(($_GET['page']!='' ? $_GET['page'] : 'home') . '.php'));
else
 require_once("404.php");
require_once('footer.php');
?>

Comment: and here is what my functions.php file look like. Have any idea about that buddy? The thing is, you got the right problem, but that method isn't working  check my functions.php                                                                       <?php

function renovate_scripts(){
wp_enqueue_style('renovate-style',get_stylesheet_uri());
wp_enqueue_script('renovate-jquery',get_template_directory_uri().'/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom.min.js');

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','renovate_scripts');